# Does 'this' refer to the element that called this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, reference, this

In the snippet below I use `$(this)` to refer to the element in which the function is being called from.  I know it is not correct because I printed out the values and it gave me 'undefined'.  How do I refer to the input element?

```
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date, obj){
                if(confirm('Is this correct?: '+ date )) {
                    $.post('edit.php', {
                        "row": $(this).data('id'),
                        "date":date,
                        "field":$(this).name,
                        "ajax":'true'
                        });
                    }
                }
    });
});
```

Here is the html element:

```
<input 
name="appvAcadVp" 
data-id="someid"  
class="datepicker" size="10" 
type="text"
placeholder="someholder"
>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery sets `this` itself, generally to point to the current element.

Otherwise, in JavaScript...

#### As a function assigned to a propety

```
var a = {
   b: function() {
      // `this` is `a`
   }
}

a.b();
```

*Except*, where the property becomes assigned to a variable. Observe...

```
var c = a.b;
c(); // the `this` will point to `window`
```

---

#### As a function assigned to a variable

```
var a = function() {
   // `this` is `window`
}

a();
```

---

#### As a Constructor

```
var C = function() {
   // `this` is `c`
}

var c = new C();
```

Note that if your forgot to instantiate with `new`, JavaScript will assign those properties to the global object (`window` in a browser).

---

#### In the global scope

```
// In global scope `this` is `window`
var d = this;
```

---

#### As called with `call()` or `apply()`

You can also set `this` explicitly with `call()` and `apply()` function methods.

---

#### Now, to your problem...

> Thanks for the explanation of 'this' but I still dont understand why the reference isn't working in my code

My apologies.

`$(this).name` won't work as `this` is now a jQuery object and has only a few properties (none of which are `name`).

Either use `$(this).attr('name')` or drop wrapping `this` with the jQuery object and just access `this.name`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of 'this' but I still dont understand why the reference isn't working in my code

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `obj` parameter is for in the onSelect function, so you'd reference `$(obj)`.  Just for reference, `this` will refer to the associated input field.

For reference, see: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ > Events > onSelect

Comment: I tried that and it was giving me 'undefined' when i printed it

Comment: `obj` is the instance of the datepicker, whilst `this` is the element that triggered the event.