# jQuery '$(this)'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why and when would you use `$(this)` instead of `this`?

Comment: Why isn't there a "general reference" close reason yet?

Comment: Everyone needs to relax someway because sometimes I find lots of folks very angried because of nothing. It's not a real question asking that? Not everyone is an absolute expert and maybe he needed some explanation. Right, very simple, but he needed it.

Answer (score 6):

You use `this` when you are in the scope of a DOM object (or any other object for that matter)

For example:

```
$('a').click(function(){
     var href = $(this).prop('href'); //refers to to this a tags href
     var href1 = this.href; //ALSO refers to to this a tags href
})
```

Answer (score 5):

When you want to use jQuery functions on the DOM element referenced by `this`.

[See the `jQuery` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> The second and third formulations of this function create a jQuery object using one or more DOM elements that were already selected in some other way. A common use of this facility is to call jQuery methods on an element that has been passed to a callback function through the keyword `this` (...)

Answer (score 1):

In some languages like JavaScript, "this" represents an object reference to enclosing one.

For example, if you've a JavaScript prototype called Person, and some method "B" of Person uses "this" in its body, "this" is current Person instance.

Applying that to jQuery, $() shortcut function accepts different types of input parameters: for example a CSS selector, a document object reference and so on. One of accepted input parameters is an instance of DOM element.

That's if you're handling "click" event for some element, you can do that:

```
$("#someIdOfSomeElement").click(function() {
      // "this" is the element with "someIdOfSomeElement" identifier
      $(this).append("hello world!");
    }
);
```

Giving "this" to $() shortcut function returns a jQuery object managing the DOM element with jQuery's properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Alex gives a really good response to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826467/does-this-refer-to-the-element-that-called-this-function)

Answer (score 0):

the $() way shows the browser that this is a jquery varible. $(this) means the current element.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is the jQuery `$()` function applied to the `this` javascript keyword. You should use it when you want to get the current `this` (a DOM element) as a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Every time `this` means an instance of `HTMLElement` and you wish to wrap it by jQuery to have it's magic available. `<p onclick="$(this).text('Clicked!');">Sun is shining.</p>`