# If this() selector is used inside a function, which selector will it refer to (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, css-selectors

For instance I have a function:

```
function somefunction () {
    $('someselector').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).remove; });
}
```

Then this function is called within:

```
$('someselector1').click(function() {
     somefunction ();
});
```

Will the `$(this)` inside `somefunction()` refer to `someselector()` or to `someselector1()`? As I understand it, `this()` refers to the selector that triggered the event, which is in this case, someselector1. Is it correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826467/does-this-refer-to-the-element-that-called-this-function

Comment: What did you discover when you tried it? Which element was faded out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will refer to a DOM element matching `someselector`. `this` is set to the element the `fadeOut` function is being applied to.

`this` inside of `someFunction` (but not inside the callback function to `fadeOut`) will be a reference to the `window` object.

```
function somefunction () {
    // "this", unless specifically set, will refer to "window"
    $('someselector').fadeOut('slow', function() { 
        // "this" refers to the element that just finished fading out.
        $(this).remove; 
    });
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9ubgH/

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's nothing magic about the `$(this)` syntax -- it just takes whatever `this` points to and feeds it to the (heavily overloaded) main jQuery entry point, and what jQuery does with depends entirely on what kind of thing it is. In particular, JQuery *doesn't know* that you got its argument from a `this`.

This is relevant because just *being in a function* does not tell you anything about what `this` will be -- that's up to the caller of the function, more or less, to decide. In your case the function happens to be called from code that sets `this` to something predictable, but that is not something you can assume about *functions in general*.

Answer (score 0):

It will refer to `someselector`.

```
$('someselector').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).remove; });
```

In the above `fadeOut` callback `this` will point to the element which it is fading so `this` will point to `someselector`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case this will refer to "someselector".

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6gdnw/